# drop down menu with links not working?

Tags: html, menu, hyperlink

I'm new to this and have no idea as to what I am doing. Whenever I try to open the menu, it doesnt drop down and it's very small. 
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="menu" id="menu">
<select onChange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="color:#fff;background-color:#FFFFFF;highlight: #CCCCCC;font-family:minecraftia_1_;font-size:8px;">
<option value=""></option>
<option style="background: #FFCCFF;" value="http://www.google.com">title 1</option>
<option style="background: #FFCC99;" value="http://www.google.com">title 2</option>
<option style="background: #FFFF99;" value="http://www.google.com">title 3</option>
<option style="background: #CCFFCC ;" value="http://www.google.com">title 4</option>
<option style="background: #99CCFF ;" value="http://www.google.com">title 5</option>
<option style="background:#9999CC;" value="http://www.google.com">title 6</option>
<option style="background: #CC99CC;" value="http://www.google.com">title 7</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu' );
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u have 2  tag "<select>" just remove one, and add id, style, and other properties...

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/6jG4S/

**HTML:-**

```
<select name="menu" id="menu" style="color:#fff;background-color:#FFFFFF;highlight: #CCCCCC;font-family:minecraftia_1_;font-size:8px;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option style="background: #FFCCFF;" value="http://www.google.com">title 1</option>
        <option style="background: #FFCC99;" value="http://www.google.com">title 2</option>
        <option style="background: #FFFF99;" value="http://www.google.com">title 3</option>
        <option style="background: #CCFFCC ;" value="http://www.google.com">title 4</option>
        <option style="background: #99CCFF ;" value="http://www.google.com">title 5</option>
        <option style="background:#9999CC;" value="http://www.google.com">title 6</option>
        <option style="background: #CC99CC;" value="http://www.google.com">title 7</option>
    </select>
```

**JS:-**

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu');
urlmenu.onchange = function () {
    window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/Fp9mH/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').change(function() {
    window.open( this.value );
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select name="menu" id="menu" style="color:#fff;background-color:#FFFFFF;highlight: #CCCCCC;font-family:minecraftia_1_;font-size:8px;">
<option value=""></option>
<option style="background: #FFCCFF;" value="http://www.google.com">title 1</option>
<option style="background: #FFCC99;" value="http://www.google.com">title 2</option>
<option style="background: #FFFF99;" value="http://www.google.com">title 3</option>
<option style="background: #CCFFCC ;" value="http://www.google.com">title 4</option>
<option style="background: #99CCFF ;" value="http://www.google.com">title 5</option>
<option style="background:#9999CC;" value="http://www.google.com">title 6</option>
<option style="background: #CC99CC;" value="http://www.google.com">title 7</option>
</select>
```